# jQuery - Get the height of a div with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I'm having an issue with reading the height of a div when I change the content

My scenario is...

I have a customisable design to which the user uploads a photo. When the photo is uploaded, the design preview is reloaded to display the image

What I need to do is read the size of the image and the size of the parent div to see if the image is too large. If it is, I need to make the image draggable so the user can set the position

My code at the moment is this...

```
function reloadPreview(data) {
    $.when(
        $.post('/ajax/get_design_preview.php', data, function(response) {
            $('#design_previews').html(response.preview);
        }, 'json')
    ).then(initDraggables);
}

function initDraggables() {
    $('.image_preview > img').each(function() {
        $(this).bind('load', function() {
            var img_height = $(this).height(),
                div_height = $(this).parent().height(),
                overlap_y = img_height - div_height;

            console.log('Img Height: ' + img_height);
            console.log('Div Height: ' + div_height);
            console.log(overlap_y);
        })
    })
}
```

I have the same code for the width which works perfectly, but the height doesn't give the correct value

The img_height and the div_height variables always match the height of the image (680px in my current test) but the div has a fixed height with overflow hidden (applied dynamically, 380px in my current test)

I had the same issue with the width but adding the $.when().then() fixed it

I also had to add the $(this).bind('load', function() { to make sure the image was loaded fully before reading its height

I know/assume it's related to the code triggering before the style for the div height is being applied, but I'm not sure how I can tell when this has happened or how to wait for it before triggering my code

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you say the height doesn't give the correct value. is it giving any value?

Comment: Yes, the console.log output is

Img Height: 680
Div Height: 680
0

The div height should read 380

Comment: and if i understand, your div is set to 380 in your css? will this 380 value change?

Comment: Yes, the div has a fixed height set in the css of 380px with an overflow of hidden. The value 380 won't change for the particular design, but the user can choose another design which is then switched via ajax and is likely to have a different height. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: ok, yeah it makes sense. i was going to suggest a conditional checking the image height against 380 if it didn't change. Is this jquery running at the end of your page?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I can't do that as each design is loaded dynamically so the height of the container needs to be read each time a new design is chosen. Yes it is at the end of the page

Comment: Have you tried adding a selector to the parent() method to make sure you're grabbing the correct div's height? $(this).parent('.image_preview').height();

Comment: Yes, I added .css('background','red') to it as well just to confirm it was looking at the correct one and it is

Comment: only thing i can think of is that the div height actually is 680 because of the child img. the height of the div in css is being ignored except to hide everything that overflows 380.

Comment: It's odd because if I use the browser console to write some javascript and read the height after, it does read it as 380 so it seems like at the time my code is triggered, the CSS from the stylesheet hasn't been applied yet

Comment: When are you executing this code first?

Comment: It's triggered when the image is uploaded by the user